# How do I send an email using python?

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

How do I send an email with python simply? I have tried a couple different ways but am unable to figure it out. I don't need the email to be secure, I am not sending any important information. No matter what I tried there was an error. I am unfamiliar with the smtplib library, but would like to learn more.

```
import smtplib

sender = '' #must fill
password = '' #must fill
receiver = '' #must fill

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()


server.login(sender, password)
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, 'Test')
print('Mail Sent')type here
```

I tested with sender, password, and receiver filled out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `user` and `password` attributes in the `login function` as written below:

```
server.login(user=sender, password=password)
server.sendmail(from_addr=sender, to_addrs=receiver, msg="Subject: Test")
```

Comment: It still didn't work. It says that my username and password were not accepted, but they are both correct.

Comment: Okay. I think you have not verified your Gmail account yet. Go to manage account and there you will see the security setting. Verify your email address with 2-step authentication and after that, you will see the password setting. There you have to create a new app and google will generate a  password for your app. Copy that password and paste it into your code.